# RStudioのデフォルト設定を変更したい

Tags: r

RStudioのメニューで Toosl→Global Options...→Code と辿ってキーバインドを変更できますが、諸事情で `~/.rstudio` を消去してしまうことが度々あります。そうすると再び手作業で上記のオプションを設定し直さないといけません。RStudioサーバーのデフォルト設定でキーバインドを変更する方法はありますか？

同様に、図のConsole On Rightもデフォルト設定としたいと考えており、合わせて教えていただけると幸いです。

[image: console on rightのメニュー]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470257/how-can-i-configure-the-default-settings-of-rstudio
英語版の方で解決策を回答いただけました

Answer (score 1):

キーボードショートカットは [Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts) に書いているように

```
    ~/.R/rstudio/keybindings/rstudio_commands.json
    ~/.R/rstudio/keybindings/editor_commands.json
```

にあります。

Windows の場合は

```
[ドキュメントフォルダ]\.R\rstudio\keybindings
```

の中にありました。

`Console On Right` の設定は Windows の場合は

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\RStudio-Desktop\monitored\user-settings
```

にありました。

設定を保存しておき、前の値と比較しながら必要な場所を更新してはいかがでしょうか？

Windows だったら WinMerge とか で比較しながら 変更点だけ修正できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。私はMacを使っていますが、.rstudio/monitored/user-settings におそらく同じものがありました。